# Listen for changes values in a form using Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

Is there a way to listen for changes (only) in FormGroup With changes, I mean only the exact key and value that changed?

For example if the input `name` changes, something like `{name: //newValue}` should be emmitet

A Solution I don't prefer is to subscribe to valueChanges of every single FormControl.

I provided a little example for testing [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xrvcmt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: to re-word your desire - you want to know if formControl value have changed, but dont want to subscribe to it?

Comment: @wentjun it's not a dublicate, since i excluded the answer in my question.

Comment: @WhiteHorse. If i have a form with 1000 inputs for example, i dont want to make 1000 subscriptions. But i also haven't found a different solution yet.

Comment: without a subscription you can't be notified in real time about the change

Comment: @dindunuffin sorry about that, I have removed it. Since the example shows that both formcontrols are inputs,  have you tried listening to the change even by doing something like this? `(change) = onInputChange($event)`

Comment: You can store the old value and compare in function, like https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2aywfa?file=src/app/app.component.ts (I'm not sure if there will be a better solution)

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the `valueChanges` on the `FormGroup`, but you will have to check for the individual values to know which `FormControl` has its value changed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pairwise](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-pairwise)

```
  .pipe(
   startWith({}),
   pairwise()
    ,tap(([previousValue, currentValue]) => {
    /** compare values here */
})
)
;
```

or

```
 .pipe(
   startWith({}),
   pairwise()
)
.subscribe(([previousValue, currentValue]) => {
    /** compare values here */
});
```